# Android: Positioning an EditText above one and below another

Tags: android, android-edittext, center, android-relativelayout

I'm using android:layout_below & android:layout_above on a RelativeLayout which contains (com.test.richedit.RichTextEditor) to attempt to always render it  above my bottom  RelativeLayout: (com.test.SetCancelButtons) & always below my LinearLayout (com.test.MenuBarTopNote) .  However when I do this the com.test.richedit.RichTextEditor doesn't show up at all.   I have also tried just using  android:layout_below="@+id/menu_bar_top"  and not specifying a android:layout_above, however, when typing many lines of text the EditText grows to the pont where is goes behind the bottom footer bar (com.test.SetCancelButtons). **I essentially want the Edit Text to always be the same size stretched between the top header bar and bottom footer bar and just the content to be scrollable**

The com.test.richedit.RichTextEditor is essentially a LinearLayout containing some buttons for styling the text in an EdiText below it.

I have used  android:layout_below & android:layout_above together before on a ListView and it worked fine, how can I achieve the same result in this case?

The xml where I'm trying to center com.test.richedit.RichTextEditor above and below 2 views:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/llayNote"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bkgrd_event_new">


           <com.test.StatusBar
                android:id="@+id/statusbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="49dip" 
                android:paddingTop="0dip"
                android:background="@drawable/statusbar"
              />


             <com.test.MenuBarTopNote
                android:id="@+id/menu_bar_top"
                android:layout_below="@+id/statusbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="104dip" 
                android:background="@drawable/menu_bar_top1"
             />

                <!-- EDIT SUBJECT -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_below="@+id/menu_bar_top" 
                    android:layout_above="@+id/setcancelbuttons"  
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"  
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                        <com.test.richedit.RichTextEditor
                            android:id="@+id/edNoteSubject" 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           />
                </RelativeLayout>


             <com.test.SetCancelButtons
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/setcancelbuttons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

The com.test.richedit.RichTextEditor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dip"
                >

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar" 
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:padding="2dip"
                      >

                <ToggleButton  
                            android:id="@+id/bold"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_toggle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textOn="B"
                            android:textOff="B"
                            android:textColor="#464646" />   

                <ToggleButton
                            android:id="@+id/italic"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_toggle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textOn="I"
                            android:textOff="I"
                            android:textColor="#464646" />

                <ToggleButton
                            android:id="@+id/underline"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_toggle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textOn="U"
                            android:textOff="U"
                            android:textColor="#464646" />

                <Button
                            android:id="@+id/size"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_toggle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:text=" SIZE "
                            android:textColor="#000000" /> 

                <Button
                            android:id="@+id/color"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_toggle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:text=" COLOR "
                            android:textColor="#000000" /> 

                <Button
                            android:id="@+id/link"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_toggle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:text=" LINK "
                            android:textColor="#464646" /> 

                <ToggleButton
                            android:id="@+id/html"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_toggle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textOn=" HTML "
                            android:textOff=" HTML "
                            android:textColor="#464646" />


<!-- 

                        <ToggleButton
                                        android:id="@+id/strike"
                                        android:background="@drawable/button_toggle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@id/underline"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/underline"
                            android:textSize="17dip"
                            android:textOn="@string/strike"
                            android:textOff="@string/strike"
                            android:textColor="#464646" />

                        <Button
                                         android:id="@+id/link" 
                                         android:background="@drawable/button_toggle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@id/strike"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/strike"
                            android:textSize="17dip"
                            android:textColor="#21759b"
                            android:text="@string/link" />  

                        <ToggleButton
                                        android:id="@+id/bquote"
                                        android:background="@drawable/button_toggle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_alignTop="@id/link"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/link"
                            android:textSize="17dip"
                            android:textOn="b-quote"
                                        android:textOff="b-quote"
                            android:textColor="#464646" />
 -->    
        </LinearLayout>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:scrollbars="vertical"
              android:gravity="top" 
              android:minLines="1"
              android:textColorLink="#21759b" /> 

    <!--   android:autoText="true" -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good in xml layout in android, but why don't you try putting "fill_parent" on both width and height of the richtexteditor and also add weight set to 1 to make sure the the object will fill all the remaining space on the view so it will look like this:

```
                    <com.test.richedit.RichTextEditor
                        android:id="@+id/edNoteSubject" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       />
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the setCancelButton above the RichTextEditor  view within the layout. Also set RichTextEditor layout's width and height to fill_parent

Comment: setCancelButton cannot be above the RichTextEditor view. setCancelButton needs to remain fixed on the bottom always.

Comment: It should be as you want as long as you are preserving layout_above and layout_below with proper id's. It is related to how xml files are apparently parsed and inflated.